# How to refresh a .bat file displaying ping?

Tags: batch-file

When I enter:

```
@echo off
ping  www.nukeduck.tk
pause>nul
```

It gets the ping, and displays the `average`, `max`, and `min`. However, I want to be able to get the ping again without exiting and re-opening the file.

I could add `-t` to make it look like this:

```
@echo off
ping -t www.nukeduck.tk
pause>nul
```

But then it constantly fetches the ping and `does not display` the average, max, and min.

Answer (score 3):

with the lines

```
:label
   ping  www.nukeduck.tk
   pause>nul
goto :label
```

Where label is any word you want it to be.
Just put `:label` where you want to jump to and `goto :label` where you want to jump from.

Comment: if you are only interested in min/max/average only, use `ping www.google.de|find "ms, "`. "ms, ", because "Minimum", "Maximum" "Average" are dependent on the localization.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, you want it to go to the start:

```
@echo off
:labelatthestartoftheprogram
ping www.nukeduck.tk
goto labelatthestartoftheprogram
```

When it gets to the `:labelatthestartoftheprogram`, it skips past it without doing anything. On the line `goto labelatthestartoftheprogram`, it finds a line which starts with a `:` and then the label you specified; execution continues from there.

I think the label can be anything alphanumeric, underscores should work too. Make your label meaningful, so when your script is 500 lines long, you can work out what the label is all about.

It will keep going forever break out of it (^C should work).

I assumed that the pause was to stop the window disappearing, so I took it out. If you want the batch file to wait until the user presses enter before pinging again, put it back in, just before the `goto` line.

Comment: The question refers to seeing the min/max/avg values and so the `-t` should not be used.

Comment: Thanks foxidrive, fixed.